# Spring Boot Post method not working with @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, rest, request-mapping

I am new to spring boot, creating a simple CRUD operations using Rest API. I have written two methods one for GET and POST. Get works fine but when I try to access post method it's not working its shows 404 error.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addStudent(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        service.saveOrUpdate(employee);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("added succcessfully", HttpStatus.OK);   
    }
```

this returns:

```
{
    
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/create"
}
```

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class EmployeeController{
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeService service;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
         service.saveOrUpdate(employee);
         return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Added");
    }
        
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> list(){
        List<Employee> employee = service.getAllEmployee();
        
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the full context / controller class?

Then please share your full request data (or at least url).

I'd recommend to use springdoc / springdoc-ui so you can see your api doc for your controller / request mapping.

Comment: you must be calling the wrong url. What is the RequestMapping on your controller? What is the RequestMapping on your GET method that is working? Which url are you calling?

Comment: i have updated the code snippet.. can u help me now? @ManuelWaltschek

Comment: What is the URL that you are invoking? are you sure you are invoking POST method and not GET ?

Comment: yes invoking post method only

Comment: Please let us know the full URL you are calling. I'd recommend to use curl for testing this:
https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-post

example: curl -d '{json}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://example.com

Or if you are using an http client like postman at least copy the full url from the request

Comment: this is the url --> http://localhost:8088/api/create i am calling it. In postman i am testing

Comment: Are you sure the bean is picked up by the ComponentScanner of Spring. If it is not then that could explain the 404 you are getting. Note that spring by default only scans packages under the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: sorry for asking this, but are you sure you set request method to `post` in postman?

Comment: is the list() method working? just to check if the controller is picked up by Spring

Comment: yes list() method is working fine.@MarcStröbel

Comment: Yes making post request in postman@HakobHakobyan

Comment: think about making a minimal reproducable example in github and share it with us.